# How to get the HTML code after the browser execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, linux, google-chrome, browser

I have problem in retrieving the HTML code containing JavaScript.

What I expect is the HTML code in which the JavaScript has been executed and only pure HTML in it like the output of browsers(e.g. Chrome).

I mean I hope that there is a Linux command or a way downloads HTML, execute JavaScript and output the page. (curl can download the page, but cannot execute the JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use case for [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) and [Phantom.JS](http://phantomjs.org/index.html). Here's a presentation that touches exactly this topic - retrieving data from dynamic pages - http://vimeo.com/66992296.

Quote from Phantom.JS website:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

So, it is a web browser that works on your server. You just need to talk to it from your script. And you can do this using e.g. [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) module for Node.JS.